# Using db arrays in set and include in symfony3

Tags: symfony

I'm a beginner in symfony. I love use database-arrays to fill out the pages in symfony as

```
<p>{{ cars.texte | nl2br }}</p>
```

Is it possible to use the same proceed in "set" and in "include", as

```
{% set tag = 'url' %}
```

letting the db complete the url

and

```
{% include "twigtemplate" %}
```

letting the db complete the template? This, as I have understood, doesn't work:

```
{% set tag =  {{ cars.color }} %}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: your question is not clear.try to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible simply remove the {{ and the }}. When you are inside of the {% %} signs you don't need the {{ and }}.

```
{% set tag =  cars.color %}
```